# Lifecycle of XML forms in context of digital signature

Tags: xml, digital-signature, infopath-forms-services

I need some platform for implementing lifecycle of XML forms in context of digital signature.

Lifecycle:

1. Designer designs a form. New form is in "open for input" state. Active components like formulas or scripts are allowed in this state to provide better user experience.
2. User inputs data with some "filler application".
3. Form is locked (static representation is created). Basically, I need XSL which will produce non interactive version of form from XML data. Final result after transformation cannot contain any active components, because it is not allowed due to legal requirements.
4. XML data and XSL transformation are signed by digital signature.

It is solution for eGovernment with aditional assumptions and restrictions:

- designer can be platform dependent
- filler should be platform independent
- in optimal case, it should be possible to input data both online (web app) and offline (desktop app)
- mature solution - preferably standard based, release versions of tools, open source solution with strong community or commercial solution provided by vendor with high probability to survive more than next 2 years:-)

One candidate is InfoPath and online forms using InfoPath Forms Services. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Web based:

- Designer: it does not matter if it is web app or desktop app
- Filler: web app is sufficient

> in optimal case, it should be possible to input data both online (web app) and offline (desktop app)